# Виртуальные Диски на Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript

Монтирую виртуальные жесткие диски [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)[diskpart](/questions/tagged/diskpart) `diskpart /s script.txt`
Предварительно создав сценарий

```sql
SELECT VDISK FILE="C:\image.vhd"
ATTACH VDISK
```

Но хочу использовать без консоли, через *VBScript*

```vbscript
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set diskpart = shell.Exec("diskpart")
```

Через `shell.Exec` всё равно открывается консоль, а через `shell.Run diskpart, 0, True` не знаю как отдавать и читать строки.

Нашёл **virtdisk.dll** с методами `AttachVirtualDisk` `DetachVirtualDisk` `GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath` ... Но не получается использовать библиотеки в VBS, несмотря на подробную документацию [Virtual Disk Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323699(v=vs.85).aspx). Поддержка методов для Windows 7 есть, но синтаксис только для C++

Каким способом можно "тихо" подключать *VHD*?
При том, что аргументом будет отдаваться только путь диска

Comment: Боюсь, всё-таки придётся писать на C#, но хочу на VBS, чтобы собрать HTA приложение с веб интерфейсом и малым размером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось создать программу, исходники и сборка тут [GitHub](https://github.com/doofyass/VHD)

<sup>Работает на чистой Windows 7 без обновлений на .NET Framework 3.5</sup>

---

Что касается системной библиотеки **virtdisk.dll**, она не представлена как COM-объект, поэтому сделал отдельно от приложения свою библиотеку на всякий случай. Но её нужно регистрировать через *RegAsm*

> <sup>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm /codebase "C:\VirtualDiskManager, x64.dll"</sup>

Отмена регистрации

> <sup>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm /u "C:\VirtualDiskManager, x64.dll"</sup>

После чего можно использовать её через VBScript

```
Set VHD = CreateObject("VirtualDiskManager.VHD")

VHD.Attach("C:\image.vhd")
VHD.Detach("C:\image.vhd")
VHD.Toggle("C:\image.vhd")
```

Comment: Возможность подключения ISO образов на Windows 10 пока не делал

Comment: Нашёл проблему. Если на сервере подключать диск, с сети к нему нет будет доступа. Думаю решу этот вопрос

Comment: Понял в чём фишка недоступности по сети. Есть разрешение к файлу vhd, а есть у подключённого диска. Diskpart игнорирует права родительской папки vhd файла, а моё приложение пока нет)